# How to clear out the info downloaded via apt-get update?

Tags: apt, package-management, automation, cache

For testing purposes, to ensure that the automation I am running will work on a "fresh" server, how can I clear all info downloaded via `apt-get update`?

`apt-get clean` does not appear to do this.

Example sequence:

1. Check `apt show somepackage` and get no results.
2. Add a new sources list in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
3. Repeat step 1 and get no results.
4. Run `apt-get update`
5. Repeat step 1 and the package is now shown.
6. **???? Run some command to reverse the effects of step 4.**
7. Repeat step 1 and get no results.

I even removed the new sources list and did an `apt-get clean` and still got a result, listed as an "additional record" and only shown in full with `-a`.

(Forgive me for not including the actual package details, but I am working against an in-house repository so the results would not be reproducible anyway.)

What is the most complete way to clear out cached information to accomplish step 6 above?

Comment: So the question is how to save all files updated by `sudo apt update` and restore them afterwards?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, no, not `apt update`; `apt-get update`.  But otherwise yes, except that I don't really care about saving them—I mostly care about wiping out the new info, and it's okay for my purposes if the old info gets wiped out at the same time.